# Maven: No build successful or [scanning for projects] message after mvn install

Tags: java, maven

I am not getting any scanning for projects or build successful or build failure message after running typing mvn install or mvn clean install.

---

```
LM-SFA-11002477:com.stubhub.mapreduce.hbasehexatodecimal navparmar$ mvn clean install
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.UnsupportedSlf4jBindingConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Downloading: https://mvnrepository.stubcorp.dev/nexus/content/groups/stubhub-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
```

---

```
LM-SFA-11002477:target navparmar$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

---

```
 mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T12:39:06-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Are you using a private artifact storage instead of maven central?

Comment: this is WARN, so you can just ignore it, you say no successful build, maybe there is another reason

Answer (score -1):

You may have included multiple slf4j jars versions in your project. Please find the dependency hierarchy tab in your pom.xml and exclude the unecessary jar version from your pom.xml.
If you still getting issue then try to build the project in debug mode.So that you will get detailed error description.

> mvn clean compile install -X

Comment: Using `compile install` install makes no sense and duplicates many life cycle phases. You can bring that to `mvn clean install -X` that's it...

Comment: Ok For that may i know why you have down voted the answer?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the case cause it shows some misunderstanding of the Maven life cycle...